# create a child process by fork() a parent process in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

It seems some answers on the site but those seem not to resolve my question.

Say,

```
#/bin/sh
fpfunction(){
n=1
while (($n<20))
do

        echo "Hello World-- $n times"
        sleep 2
        echo "Hello World2-- $n times"
        n=$(( n+1 ))
done
}

fork(){
    count=0
    while (($count<=10))
    do
      fpfunction &
      count=$(( count+1 ))
    done
}

fork
```

---

I am expecting to "fork" this parent process to the number of 10 child processes.

The way I check that those child processes are actually created is to type "ps -l" command.

I am a newbie to the shell world and please let me know how to archive this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ampersand (`&`) after a command will run it in a forked subshell.

```
fpfunction &
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw this post. I did add fpfunction & and yes, the function was really executed. However, when I checked "ps -l" command, it seems nothing to change. I was expecting that this command will display the child processes I forked from parent process.

Comment: `fpfunction` is not a command per se, it is a shell function. As such, it is the shell that will show up in `ps`.

Comment: I just edited my shell. A fork function can be executed but I dont understand what do you mean by "the shell that will show up in ps".

Comment: That's because you forgot to read the bit that comes before it.